# Entity Framework core one to one relationship generate one to many in SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework-core

For one-to-one relationship in Entity Framework core (rc1 or rc2) based on this tutorial http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#one-to-one, I use this code:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BlogImage> BlogImages { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .HasOne(p => p.BlogImage)
            .WithOne(i => i.Blog)
            .HasForeignKey<BlogImage>(b => b.BlogForeignKey);
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public BlogImage BlogImage { get; set; }
}

public class BlogImage
{
    public int BlogImageId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }

    public int BlogForeignKey { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

But after running the migration, and checking the database, I noticed that the generated tables have the following relationship:

[image]

What is solution?

Comment: What is the *problem* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BlogImageId` should be `BlogImage`'s primary key *and* the foreign key to `Blog`:

```cs
public class BlogImage
{
    public int BlogImageId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    // Removed BlogForeignKey

    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
    .HasOne(p => p.BlogImage)
    .WithOne(i => i.Blog)
    .HasForeignKey<BlogImage>(b => b.BlogImageId); // BlogImageId is FK
```

Comment: I test like this code before, this code throw exception in migration

Comment: Well, this is what you need if you want a 1:1 association. If would have helped if you'd mentioned your own efforts and migration problems in your question. Also *throw exception* isn't very informative. What is the exception?

Comment: your code is ok, I test like this code, and difference is that BlogImageId in BlogImage entity was BlogId. and exception occur. System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'WebApplication18.Data.BlogImage' requires a key to be defined.    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ModelValidator.ShowError(String message), anyway your code is ok.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good, and you are in fact creating a 1:1 relationship between `Blog` and `BlogImage` objects and EF Core recognizes this by allowing you to have a bidirectional association between these two objects.

The only problem is that EF Core *failed* to translate this one to one association to the database by creating a unique constraint on `BlogForeignKey` column and as a result you have a one to one association in your object model which is mapped to a one to many relationship in your database.

This is a [*Bug in EF Core*](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5623)
 which will be fixed in the final release.

Now if you want to create a *[Shared Primary Key Association](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations)* then the answer provided by @Gert is the way to go but if your intention was to create your one to one association on a unique foreign key (i.e. BlogForeignKey) or basically a [*One-to-One Foreign Key Association*](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations) then don't change your code, just manually create a unique constraint on BlogForeignKey column and wait for the RTM version which is [scheduled](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/06/net-core-rc2-improvements-schedule-and-roadmap/) to come out by the end of this month.