# How to create one to zero or one relationship in Entity Framework code-first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to create a one to zero or one relationship between the `Institution` and `Address` tables. I am essentially expecting the `AddressId` column will be included in the `Institution` table after the relationship is established.

This is my code:

```
public class Institution
{
    public int InstitutionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //1 to 1 with Address
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    //one--to-many with Professor
    public virtual IList<Professor> Profesors { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    public virtual Institution Institution { get; set; }
}
```

In the context class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Institution>()
            .HasOptional(i => i.Address)
            .WithRequired(ad => ad.Institution);
```

When I see the database diagram I see a relationship established between these two tables - with a yellow colored key on both ends of the line - but neither the `AddressId` column is included in the `Institution` table nor the `InstitutionId` is included in the `Address` table.

Thanks

Comment: See [Shared Primary Key Associations](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations)

Answer (score 2):

Basically your intention is to create a *[One-to-One Foreign Key Association](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations)* while EF is giving you a *[Shared Primary Key Association](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-3-shared-primary-key-associations)* because well, EF 6 does *not* support the former and Shared Primary Key Association is the only association type EF 6 supports when it comes to 1:1 entity relationships.

Your options apart from what you have right now are:

1. You can work around this and create a unidirectional one to many association from Address to Institution and then create a unique constraint on AddressId FK on Institution table. SQL Server will see this relationship as a 1:1 while your object model sees an Address on Institution object but (of course) this option won't work for you if you want to also see a Institution on Address object (basically if you need a bidirectional 1:1 association). If you are interested in this option then I explain this workaround in [*here*](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations).
2. I kept saying EF 6 in the lines above because If you can upgrade then EF Core (formerly EF 7) supports One-to-One Foreign Key Associations because of its new support for alternate keys. Basically it means it now supports unique constraints which is essential for One-to-One Foreign Key Associations.

Comment: Thank you @MortezaManavi, the info about EF7 for me is also new ++1

Comment: You're welcome. If you decide to give 1:1 associatios on EF Core a try then please be aware that it currently has a bug which I explained in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536637/entity-framework-core-one-to-one-relationship-generate-one-to-many-in-sql-server/37648998#37648998